# make a plugin abort the build process with maven

Tags: java, maven

I have written a maven plugin which under certain conditions throws a

```
MojoExecutionException
```

I would like my plugin to abort the build process if such an exception is thrown. Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html):

> The execute method can throw two exceptions:
>
> - `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException` if an unexpected problem occurs. Throwing this exception causes a "BUILD ERROR" message to be displayed.
> - `org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException` if an expected problem (such as a compilation failure) occurs. Throwing this exception causes a "BUILD FAILURE" message to be displayed.

So you will have to change the thrown exception